# What is the best way of declaring and implementing two java classes?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have two classes one is called Modifiers and the other is called Options. Modifiers has an id, name and a group of options associated with it. While Options (or each option) has a name and price. Each option is associated with only one Modifier. What is the best way of Writing these classes to take into account their relationship. In my application, the user has to enter the name of the Modifier, then they have to enter the name and price of each option. Each modifier can have as many options as necessary. Here are the classes and how I am using them for now:the user has to enter the name of the Modifier, then they have to enter the name and price of each option. Each modifier can have as many options as necessary. Here are the classes and how I am using them for now:

```
public class Modifier {
    int id;
    String name;
    Options [] options;

    public Modifier() {
    }

    public Modifier(String name, Options[] options) {
        this.name = name;
        this.options = options;
    }

    public Modifier(int id, String name, Options[] options) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.options = options;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Options[] getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public void setOptions(Options[] options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
}
```

I am currently add the group of Options as an array. Here is the Options class.

```
public class Options {
    int id;
    String name;

    public Options() {
    }

    public Options(String name, long price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Options(int id, String name, long price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    long price;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(long price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}

And in my main:
 Options sausage = new Options("sausage",23);
        Options olives = new Options("olives", 24);
        Options bacon = new Options("bacon", 25);

        Options [] toppings = {sausage, olives, bacon};

        Modifier pizza_toppings = new Modifier(1, "Pizza toppings",toppings);
```

I plan on using an SQLIte DB so I need to find an efficient way of doing this.

Comment: you could add one field to Options class which save modifier id, then with sqlite you will create two tables one for modifiers and one for options, and when you retrieve data from it, you use foriegn key to build your object. whoever your classes now looks fine, you may just save modifiers ids in options table and the vice versa like this:
modifier table [modifierId, name] - option table [optionId - name - modifierId]

Comment: The issue with that is that the modifier and ID are created at the same time, how can I get the id of the modifier at that instance.

Comment: You don't create modifier without id right? I can't see any problem, you can assign the id on constructor, then assign same id for modifier id on for each option on options list.

Comment: the id is created automatically. its auto-increment

Answer (score 0):

you could add one field to Options class which save modifier id, then with sqlite you will create two tables one for modifiers and one for options, and when you retrieve data from it, you use foreign key to build your object. whoever your classes now looks fine, you may just save modifiers ids in options table and the vice versa like this:

> modifier table [modifierId, name] - option table [optionId, name, modifierId]

Comment: the user creates both the modifier and its options at the same time. Also modifier I.Ds are auto incremented.